# How do I get links to reliably pop out of embedded Google Maps frame?

Tags: google-maps, embed

We have created a map with a bunch of locations added for meetings we sponsor. Each location has a link in the description to launch out to that meeting's agenda/location info/etc. page (usually either a meetup.com meeting or a Facebook group page).

This all works wonderfully when you are looking at the map directly on [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?hl=en&gl=us&ptab=0&ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=109928460336645833735.000488240bdb84fd4206e&ll=44.161818,-111.621094&spn=82.290773,158.027344&z=3&source=embed), but when we embed the map into another webpage, the links in the description get opened in the embedded frame and are pretty much unusable. You used to see this on [our page](http://www.smugmug.com/smugs/find/) by clicking on any of the green markers, then clicking the link in its description.

But here's the kicker: some browsers (Chrome, Safari) do the right thing and launch that link in the window/tab not in the iframe. Other browsers (IE, Firefox) launch the new link in the iframe.

The logical/obvious solution to this is to put a target on the anchor in the description, but Google strips them out, no matter what I put there. So, anyone have any ideas on how to make this work the same in all browsers (preferably like Chrome and Safari)?

---

(I made it past tense as we've put the frame breaker into place so you can't easily see the failure on our map anymore, but you could still reproduce this with your own map if you want to play with it.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution we have come up with so far... I'm really hoping someone out there has a better idea.

We're going to build a frame breaker page that will do a small bit of HTML/JS that will detect if it's in a frame, if so it will reload itself in the top frame, otherwise it will reload the URL we pass to it as an argument. Then we'll recode all of our markers to use that instead of directly linking to the destination site.